# How to properly configure vcpkg C++ includePath on macOS VS Code?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, path, vcpkg

I installed vcpkg with Homebrew. I followed to instructions on official vcpkg docs.

I used this command:

```
vcpkg integrate project
```

and got the following message:

```
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.
CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2020.11-1/libexec/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

I added to VS Code settings.json

```
"cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "/usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2020.11-1/libexec/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
  }
```

and to c_cpp_properties.json includePath:

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2020.11-1/libexec/packages/**"
```

or:

```
"/usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2020.11-1/libexec/packages"
```

and VS Code still can't find any vcpkg library.
I've got the error:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/emilmordarski/Uczelnia/PG/teams/freeglut3.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "freeglut/include/GL/glut.h"C/C++(1696)
```

I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.1.
I have installed C/C++, Cmake and few more extensions to support C++ in VS Code.

I also tried install vcpkg cloning git repo, but an effect was the same. Any ideas?